# CGLIB throws IllegalArgumentException when trying to use a Spock Spy

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I'm trying to spy my service class but I'm getting below exception, can you please help what I'm doing wrong here:

I tried to create Spy object using below code but is not working as expected

```
def myService = Spy(MyService)
```

**MyInterface.groovy**

```
interface MyInterface<T> {

    public String welcome(T t);

}
```

**MyService.groovy**

```
@Service
class MyService implements MyInterface<WelcomeMessage> { 

@Override
    String welcome(WelcomeMessage welcomeMessage) {

    try { 
        // Business logic

    } catch (ex) { 

        // Catch Exception
    }

    }

}

import spock.lang.Specification
class myServiceTest extends Specification {
    def "testWelcome"() {
        setup: "create mock object"
        def myService = Spy(MyService)

        and: " and object with mock data"
        when: "invoke welcomeMessage"
        then: "Expecting no exception is thrown"
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.BridgeMethodResolver.resolveAll(BridgeMethodResolver.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitMethods(Enhancer.java:911)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:498)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:154)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:68)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.createInternal(JavaMockFactory.java:59)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:40)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:51)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:296)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:286)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.SpyImpl(SpecInternals.java:169)
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: I hope it is okay that I changed the subject to more clearly state your problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your versions of `spring`, `spock` and `cglib`?

For these ones I could not reproduce the described issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The code I have is almost the same (instead `WelcomeMessage` I use `String`):

**MyInterface.groovy**

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    String welcome(T t);
}
```

**MyService.groovy**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class MyService implements MyInterface<String> {
    @Override
    String welcome(String welcomeMessage) {
        return welcomeMessage
    }
}
```

**MyServiceTest.groovy**

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyServiceTest extends Specification {
    def "Welcome"() {
        setup: "create mock object"
        def myService = Spy(MyService)

        when: "invoke welcomeMessage"
        def actual = myService.welcome("any")

        then:
        actual == "any"
    }
}
```